# How to locate pseudo element like ::before via selenium2library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, selenium2library

[image]

I do not know how to locate the pseudo element ,while using robotframework-selenium2Library to do web test.
Any help is useful.Thanks.

the test script is like below:
    Click Element    my_element
 ID:
Click Element | id=my_element Matches by @id attribute

Thank to Alex Bruce, it works.

Comment: why don't you use the css to locate the element     find_element_by_css_selector("span.layui-layer-setwin>a")

Comment: How do you want to handle pseudo element? What is desired output?

Comment: it is auto test script like below: click element   "span.layui-layer-setwin>a"

Comment: @Alex Bruce , I am tyring

Comment: @DieseXu, if you want to click, then you need `<a>` element. `::before` is not a part of `DOM`, so you cannot locate and click it

Comment: @ Andersson It works by css "span.layui-layer-setwin>a", although I have not understand css yet.Thanks all the way.

Answer (score -1):

Pseudo web elements wont be part of DOM so it is not possible to get attribute value from selenium2library. Instead we can get it from Execute Javascript like below snippet.

```
${attribute_value}=    Execute Javascript    return window.getComputedStyle(${element},${pseudo_element}).getPropertyValue('${attribute}');
```

I was looking for same and found great working code in below link. (JFI - No promo)

Check key "Get Pseudo Element CSS Attribute Value" in the below link.

https://adiralashivaprasad.blogspot.com/2018/06/how-to-get-pseudo-element-css-attribute.html